# Reaching unwind handlers

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, stack-unwinding

Any idea why code that looks like this

```
list<Foo> fooList;
processList(&fooList);
```

Generates the following machine code

```
    lea     rax, [rbp-48]
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    processList(std::__cxx11::list<Foo, std::allocator<Foo> >*)
    lea     rax, [rbp-48]
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    std::__cxx11::list<Foo, std::allocator<Foo> >::~list()
    jmp     .L11
    mov     rbx, rax
    lea     rax, [rbp-48]
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    std::__cxx11::list<Foo, std::allocator<Foo> >::~list()
    mov     rax, rbx
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    _Unwind_Resume
.L11:
    add     rsp, 40
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

In particular, I don't see any paths leading to the line after the unconditional `jmp .L11`

(this is with GCC 6.2 with no optimization, generated on compiler explorer)

For comparison, clang 5.0.0 produces

```
    call    processList(std::__cxx11::list<Foo, std::allocator<Foo> >*)
    jmp     .LBB5_1
.LBB5_1:
    lea     rdi, [rbp - 24]
    call    std::__cxx11::list<Foo, std::allocator<Foo> >::~list()
    add     rsp, 48
    pop     rbp
    ret
    lea     rdi, [rbp - 24]
    mov     ecx, edx
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 32], rax
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 36], ecx
    call    std::__cxx11::list<Foo, std::allocator<Foo> >::~list()
    mov     rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 32]
    call    _Unwind_Resume
```

Again there is an unconditional jump to a return block, and and unwind block (starting with the second `lea rdi`) that seems unreachable.

Comment: Have you tried compiling wih optimization enabled?

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't my question.

Comment: Exception handlers *shouldn't* be normally reachable, that's the point

Comment: To me this looks like *can't* be reached rather than *shouldn't*

Comment: Ok let me reword it: exception handlers are unreachable through normal control flow. You're only looking at normal control flow, so they are unreachable.

Comment: Are you saying that it is reachable in abnormal flow? How?

Comment: Through the unwinding process, so look at the .eh_frame and such

Comment: @PaulFloyd If you compile without optimizations, it is not unusal to see dead (unreachable) code in the binary.  After all, you forbade the compile to remove such code by turning off the optimizer.

Comment: @harold I'll have a look to try to find out the .eh_frame mechanism

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of research on C++ exception mechanisms, my conclusion is that the process is as follows:

1. At the point of exception throw, `__cxa_throw` gets called. This is somewhat like `longjmp()` in that the function gets called but never returns. The function performs two main tasks

   - It walks up the call stack looking for a catch. If it doesn't find any, `std::terminate` gets called.
   - If it does find a catch block then it calls all of the unwind handlers between the current function and the catch block, then calls the catch block.

Back to my original machine code (with filtering turned off in compiler explorer). My comments after the hashes.

```
    # this is the normative path
    call    std::list<Handle, std::allocator<Handle> >::~list()
    # unconditional jump around the unwind handler
    jmp     .L11
.L10:
    # unwind handler code, calls the local variable destructor
    mov     rbx, rax
    .loc 2 30 0
    lea     rax, [rbp-32]
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    std::list<Handle, std::allocator<Foo> >::~list()
    mov     rax, rbx
    mov     rdi, rax
.LEHB1:
    # carry on unwinding
    call    _Unwind_Resume

.L11:
```

Then there is the exception table

```
   .section        .gcc_except_table,"a",@progbits
.LLSDA1386:
    .byte   0xff
    .byte   0xff
    .byte   0x1
    .uleb128 .LLSDACSE1386-.LLSDACSB1386
.LLSDACSB1386:
    # entry for unwind handler
    .uleb128 .LEHB0-.LFB1386
    .uleb128 .LEHE0-.LEHB0
    .uleb128 .L10-.LFB1386
    .uleb128 0
    .uleb128 .LEHB1-.LFB1386
    .uleb128 .LEHE1-.LEHB1
    .uleb128 0
    .uleb128 0
```

I guess that the unwind handler function can work out the positions of the unwind handler blocks from the addresses on the stack and the offsets in this table.